# Flickity Carousel - autoPlay stops after user interaction

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Flickity Carousel which contains a testimonial. The carousel is set to autoplay.

The problem is if the user clicks on the dots or on the next / previous button the autoPlay stops.

This is what I have:

JS

```
var flkty = new Flickity( '.main-gallery', {
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true,
  wrapAround: true,
  prevNextButtons: true,
  autoPlay: 5000
});
```

HTML

```
  <div class="main-gallery">
  <div class="gallery-cell">
    <div class="testimonial">
      <p class="testimonial-quote" style="font-style: italic;">"Comment."</p>
      <span class="testimonial-author">Author</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cell">
     <div class="testimonial">
      <p class="testimonial-quote">"Comment."</p>
      <span class="testimonial-author">Author</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cell">
        <div class="testimonial">
      <p class="testimonial-quote">"Comment."</p>
      <span class="testimonial-author">Author</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please assist me to let the autoPlay continue and don't stop after a user is interacting with the dots or next/prev button.

Comment: Try `pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false`, tell how it went.

Comment: I already tried `pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false` It doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Try: commenting out the line `this.on( 'uiChange', this.stopPlayer );` in the [flickity.pkgd.js](https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2.1.2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this question the following way:

- Catch 'pointerUp' event that is called after you interact with the slider.
- Resume auto play when event is fired.

The following code demonstrates this behavior:

```
currentFlickity.on('pointerUp', function (event, pointer) {
        currentFlickity.player.play();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This part of code should help

```
change: () => {
  (flRef as any).current?.flkty.player.play()
}
```

And a full example inside the functional component with React hooks 
`change` event will fire on every slide change (index change)

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import Flickity from 'react-flickity-component'
import { Link } from '../../i18n'

export default function HomeSlider(props) {
  const { slides} = props 

  const flRef = useRef()

  return (
    <div className="home-slider">
      <Flickity 
        flickityRef={() => {}}
        ref={flRef}
        static
        options={{
          wrapAround: true, 
          freeScroll: false, 
          initialIndex: 1, 
          autoPlay: 6000,
          lazyLoad: true,
          adaptiveHeight: true,
          on: {
            ready: () => {
              console.log('Flickity ready', flRef.current)
            },
            change: () => {
              (flRef as any).current?.flkty.player.play()
            }
          }
        } as any}>
          {
            slides?.length > 0 && slides.map(slide => (
              <div className="slide" key={slide.id}>
                <Link href={slide?.details_button_url || '/'}>
                  <img src={slide.image_url} />
                </Link>
              </div>
            ))
          }
      </Flickity>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the other solutions stop and restart the player when clicking, which is not ideal. To prevent the player from stopping the timer at all when clicking you can do this:

```
$( '.my-slider' ).flickity( {
    autoPlay: 5000,
    pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false,
    on: {
        ready: function() {
            this.off( 'uiChange', this.stopPlayer );
            this.off( 'pointerDown', this.stopPlayer );
        }
    }
} );
```

This is for Flickity v2.3.0. I'm not sure if it works in other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.flickity.on(`uiChange`, function() {
        currentFlickity.player.play();
      });
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must replay the autoplay whenever [pointerUp](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/events.html#pointerup) and [change](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/events.html#change) are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I added css pointer-events block and it work in my project.

```css
.flickity-enabled {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```